# Mock useSearchParams react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this custom hook

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const useZRoutes = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { search, hash } = useLocation();
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  return {
    getQueryParam: <T>(key: string): T | null => {
      if (searchParams.has(key)) {
        const value = searchParams.get(key);
        return value as unknown as T;
      }

      return null;
    },
    deleteQueryParam: (key: string): void => {
      if (searchParams.has(key)) {
        searchParams.delete(key);
        setSearchParams(searchParams);
      }
    },
    extendsNavigate: (pathname: string) => navigate({ pathname, search, hash }),
  };
};

export { useZRoutes };
```

Now, I need to test the `getQueryParam` function but I can't update the URL with query param.

I tried to mock useSearchParams with `Object.defineProperty`
and with
`jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({ ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts useSearchParams: () => ("pid=123"), }));`

and my test isn't passed.
what should I do?

Answer (score 16):

Instead of attempting to mock `useSearchParams`, I would recommend wrapping a component that is using your custom hook with a `MemoryRouter` and passing in your search params as `initialEntries`.

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('My component using the useZRoutes hook', () => {    
  it('should do something', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["?pid=123"]}>
        <TestComponentUsingHook />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )
    // expect something
  })
})
```

Comment: This works for passing initial search params, but what if you wanted to assert search params changed?

Comment: @Titenis you can create another component SearchParamsObserver that internally uses useSearchParams and calls a callback whenever they change. Just render this component in your test next to the component you are testing.

Answer (score 4):

you could just mock URLSearchParams, like so,

```
  jest.spyOn(
    URLSearchParams.prototype,
    'get'
  ).mockImplementation(
    (key) => "foo"
  );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Mock useSearchParams

```
const searchParams = { "pid": "123"};
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...(jest.requireActual('react-router-dom') as object),
  useSearchParams: () => [searchParams]
}));
```

Comment: The important part of this answer is that you need to return an ARRAY. So you can't use `jest.fn()` to mock this. The simples way would be `() => []`.

Answer (score 1):

Passing initialEntries only string we will have this error in Typescript

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'InitialEntry[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
components.d.ts(9, 5): 
The expected type comes from property 'initialEntries' 
which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & MemoryRouterProps'
```

instead of string, you can pass

`["/path?pid=123"]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking for TypeScript typesafe version: here is the mock that will work for react-router V6.4+ for both cases: initial urlParams and updates via setParams function that is returned as second argument

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import * as reactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom'

type SetParams = ReturnType<typeof reactRouterDom.useSearchParams>['1']

// from react-router-dom github
function createSearchParams(init: reactRouterDom.URLSearchParamsInit = ''): URLSearchParams {
  return new URLSearchParams(
    typeof init === 'string' || Array.isArray(init) || init instanceof URLSearchParams
      ? init
      : Object.keys(init).reduce<reactRouterDom.ParamKeyValuePair[]>((memo, key) => {
          const value = init[key]
          return memo.concat(Array.isArray(value) ? value.map((v) => [key, v]) : [[key, value]])
        }, []),
  )
}

export const useSearchParamsMock: typeof reactRouterDom.useSearchParams = (
  defaultInit: reactRouterDom.URLSearchParamsInit | undefined,
) => {
  const location = reactRouterDom.useLocation()
  const [params, setParams] = useState<URLSearchParams>(
    new URLSearchParams(createSearchParams(defaultInit ?? location.search)),
  )
  const setParamsMock: SetParams = (nextInit) => {
    const newSearchParams = createSearchParams(
      typeof nextInit === 'function' ? nextInit(params) : nextInit,
    )
    setParams(newSearchParams)
  }

  return [params, setParamsMock]
}
```

Then in the actual test you can use it with `jest` or `vi` (vitest mocking lib)

Vitests:

```
    vi.spyOn(reactRouterDom, 'useSearchParams').mockImplementation(useSearchParamsMock)
```

Jest

```
    jest.spyOn(reactRouterDom, 'useSearchParams').mockImplementation(useSearchParamsMock)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mock it like this. Enough to get my test to pass, but would love comments on how to elaborate on it.

```js
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';

jest.mock('next/navigation', () => ({
  useSearchParams: jest.fn(),
}));

const mockGet = jest.fn();
mockGet.mockReturnValue('5000');

(useSearchParams as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue({
  get: mockGet,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a long time trying many things, this works for me using mockImplementation function:

```
describe('test', () => {
  test('should ...', async () => {
    ...
    useSearchParams.mockImplementation(() => [new URLSearchParams({ autoplay: '1' })]);...
  });

});
```